# In Visual Studio 2022, using ASP NET Webforms how do I fix element is not a known element?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2022

Unable to use intelli sense and the warning on almost all lines. Visual Studio does not recognize not even a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem removing the MasterPageFile tag on top-Page tag-and selecting the master page again.